# Symfony ClassLoader Component example

Tags: php, autoloader, psr-0, symfony-components

I'm trying to set up a simple example in order to understand how the ClassLoader Component of Symfony and the new [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard work.

First I created Bar.php:

```
namespace Acme;

class Bar 
{
    // Implementation
    public static function helloWorld() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Then I created a autoloader.php (under the vendor path I have the ClassLoader component):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/class-loader/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();

$loader->registerNamespace('Acme', __DIR__);
```

Lastly I created Foo.php:

```
require_once 'autoloader.php';

use Acme;

class Foo extends Bar
{
    // Implementation
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo::helloWorld();
```

But when I execute:

```
$ php Foo.php
```

I get the following error message:

> PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Acme' has no
>   effect in  Foo.php on line 4
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Bar' not found in Foo.php on line 7

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**:

If instead of using `namespace Acme` I use `namespace Acme\Bar` in `Bar.php`, I get the same error message as shown above.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was going on wrong. The problem was that the UniversalClassLoader class that follows the standard PSR-0, requires that the files with the namespaces cannot be in the root directory, and must be created under a minimum of one directory.

Here is the code in case someone wants to try the example.

autoloader.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';
$loader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array('Acme' => __DIR__ . '/src'));
$loader->register();
```

./src/Acme/Bar.php

```
namespace Acme;

class Bar 
{
    // Implementation
    public static function helloWorld() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

./src/Acme/Foo.php

```
namespace Acme;

require_once '../../autoloader.php';

use Acme\Bar;

class Foo extends Bar
{
    // Implementation
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo::helloWorld();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an entire namespace, you have tu use Acme\Bar.

Comment: If I use `Acme\Bar` as namespace in `Bar.php` I get the same error, I'll update the question in order to explain this.